# Does my MergeSort still have O(nlogn) time complexity, why it runs so slow?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, mergesort

I'm learning Merge Sort on Coursera. I followed their pseudocode and implement it as below:

```
# First, I create a Merge function to merge two sorted lists from the main function
# For example, two lists b=[1,5] and c=[2,4] will become d=[1,2,4,5]
# I do this by comparing the first ele of each list, moving the smaller one into list d (move = add ele to list d + remove ele from list a/b)
# Then when a list becomes [], add the rest of another list to list d

def merge(b, c):
    
    d = []
    while b != [] and c != []:
        fb = b[0] # First ele of list b
        fc = c[0] # First ele of list a
        if fb <= fc: # Compare, then move (append+remove)
            d.append(fb)
            b.remove(fb)
        else:
            d.append(fc)
            c.remove(fc)
    # When a list become [], add the rest of other list to d
    d.extend(b)
    d.extend(c)

    return d

# Then come my main Merge Sort function
def merge_sort(a, l, r): # l = 1, r = len(a), I will index each ele from 1 to n (instead of start at 0)

    if (r-l) == 0: # Base case, list contain only 1 ele, return that ele (I index from 1 so need to minus 1)
        return [a[l-1]]
# Then divide, sort and merge
    m = (l+r)//2
    b = merge_sort(a, l, m)
    c = merge_sort(a, m+1, r)

    d = merge(b, c)

    return d

a = [5, 4, 6, 1, 2, 7, 3]
n = len(a)
print(merge_sort(a, 1, n))
```

I got the expected output. But when I put the code on [codelearn.io - 44](https://codelearn.io/learning/data-structure-and-algorithms/853804), I failed 1 test due to the **time limit** (that test case contains a very long list). When I tried the optimal code on [GeekForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/), it run much faster and pass the test case. Still, it's just **executed time**, not **time complexity** so I'm not sure if my code is still `O(NlogN)` or not.

I don't know, I just followed Coursera's pseudocode (divide - sort - merge), they also explained that the Merge function is `O(n)`, and the MergeSort is `O(log2n)`, so it should be `O(nlogn)`. But it runs much slower than the optimal code.

Here is the [pseudocode](https://i.upanh.org/2022/05/07/merge.png) I'm following for anyone who is interested.

Comment: `d.remove()` and `c.remove()` are O(n) operations. Thus your merge sort is not O(n log n), it's probably O(n^2 log n) or similar.

Comment: The usual way is to use indices into the two lists to be merged, and not modify the lists at all.

Comment: @PaulHankin It's O(n^2), see the [Case 3 example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Case_3_example).

Answer (score 0):

The code and pseudo code are relatively slow implementations. Example of a standard optimized top down merge sort as shown in Wikipedia article. It makes a one time copy of the array, then alternates direction of merge based on level of recursion.

```
def sort(a):
    if(len(a) < 2):                     # if nothing to do, return
        return
    b = a[:]                            # b = copy of a
    sortr(b, a, 0, len(a))              # merge sort

def sortr(b, a, beg, end):              # merge sort
    if((end - beg) < 2):                # if < 2 elements
        return                          #   return
    mid = (beg+end)//2                  # set mid point
    sortr(a, b, beg, mid)               # merge sort left  half to b
    sortr(a, b, mid, end)               # merge sort right half to b
    mrg(b, a, beg, mid, end)            # merge halves   from b to a

def mrg(a, b, ll, rr, ee):              # merge a pair of runs from a to b
    o = ll                              # o = b[]        index
    l = ll                              # l = a[] left   index
    r = rr                              # r = a[] right  index
    while True:
        if(a[l] <= a[r]):               # if a[l] <= a[r]
            b[o] = a[l]                 #   copy a[l]
            o += 1
            l += 1
            if(l < rr):                 #   if not end of left run
                continue                #     continue (back to while)
            b[o:ee] = a[r:ee]           #   else copy rest of right run
            return                      #     and return
        else:                           # else a[l] > a[r]
            b[o] = a[r]                 #   copy a[r]
            o += 1
            r += 1
            if(r < ee):                 #   if not end of right run
                continue                #     continue (back to while)
            b[o:ee] = a[l:rr]           #   else copy rest of left run
            return                      #     and return
```